# mingw C++ won't compile j0 funciton

Tags: windows, c++11, mingw, cmath

I'm trying to compile a program on Windows using MingW (msys2) and it fails with the j0 function. On Linux it compiles no problem. It seems to hate when I use the -std=c++11 flag on the compiler. How can I get this to compile properly and with the -std=c++11 flag on?

Sample code:

```
#include <cmath>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    float test = j0( 5 );
}
```

Output

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
test.cpp:6:21: error: 'j0' was not declared in this scope
  float test = j0( 5 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, MinGW defines the Bessel functions only when `__STRICT_ANSI__` is not defined, and it is defined when `-std=c++11` is specified. I was able to get your code to compile in MinGW by adding `#undef __STRICT_ANSI__` at the top of the file. See https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/feature-requests/68/

You might also try `-std=gnu++11` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19667112/10077

Comment: This is a really excellent answer. Adding -std=gnu++11 did solve the problem wonderfully.